# Return all values if parameter is blank Power Query

Tags: powerquery, m

I am using parameters to filter my query but cannot seem to find the right code to either not filter if the parameter is blank or return all results if the parameter is blank. I used to use wildcards on either side of my parameter in Microsoft Query but cannot find a wildcard that works in Power Query.

Here is my current filter:

```
Table.SelectRows(
    #"Removed Columns",
    each Text.Contains([Description], ParameterDescription)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a null check to the condition.

```
each ParameterDescription = null or Text.Contains([Description], ParameterDescription)
```